# Why am I getting errors freeing memory allocated by apriltags image_u8_create() and stored in 2D vector of pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc, apriltags

I am attempting to detect apriltags in image streams. Because the images come in from multiple sources at a high rate, detecting the tags in the image callback will take too long, causing images to be dropped due to missed callbacks. I have decided to store images for a few seconds at a time, and run detection on the images afterwards. Between each run of images, I would like to free all the used memory, as I will need to store multiple GB of data for each ~5 second run and images/framerates/sources change between runs.

I am using the image_u8_t type that comes with the [apriltag library](https://github.com/AprilRobotics/apriltag) compiled from source:

```
typedef struct image_u8 image_u8_t;
struct image_u8
{
    const int32_t width;
    const int32_t height;
    const int32_t stride;
    uint8_t *buf;
};
```

and which has `create()` and `destroy()` functions (`create()` is a wrapper that fills in some default values for the shown `create_from_stride()`, namely stride = width:

```
image_u8_t *image_u8_create_stride(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, unsigned int stride)
{
    uint8_t *buf = calloc(height*stride, sizeof(uint8_t));

    // const initializer
    image_u8_t tmp = { .width = width, .height = height, .stride = stride, .buf = buf };

    image_u8_t *im = calloc(1, sizeof(image_u8_t));
    memcpy(im, &tmp, sizeof(image_u8_t));
    return im;
}

void image_u8_destroy(image_u8_t *im)
{
    if (!im)
        return;
    free(im->buf);
    free(im);
}
```

The first run of images always goes as expected, however, on the second, I consistently get errors freeing memory. It seems that although the vectors report a size=0 after using `clear()`, it is retaining values at the front of the vector and iterating through them, attempting to double free memory. A minimum example of code that also shows the error is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <apriltag/apriltag.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<image_u8_t *>> images(2);

void create_images(int i){
  image_u8_t * img;
  img = image_u8_create(1920, 1200);
  images.at(i).push_back(img);
}

int main() {
  char c;

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
      create_images(j);
    }
  }
  // This works fine
  for (auto vec : images){
    for (auto img : vec){
      image_u8_destroy(img);
    }
    vec.clear();
  }
  // Just to pause and inspect output
  cin >> c;

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
      create_images(j);
    }
  }
  // This causes a segfault/free() error 
  for (auto vec : images){
    for (auto img : vec){
      image_u8_destroy(img);
    }
    vec.clear();
  }

}
```

Printing the pointer to be freed (`im->buf`) shows what seems to be happening:

```
Freeing image buffer at **0x7ff8cf22e010**
Freeing image buffer at 0x7ff8cedc8010
Freeing image buffer at 0x7ff8ce962010
Freeing image buffer at 0x7ff8ceffb010
Freeing image buffer at 0x7ff8ceb95010
Freeing image buffer at 0x7ff8ce72f010
c
Freeing image buffer at **0x7ff8cf22e010**
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and the output from my real program shows a more specific but similar problem:

```
img u8 vector length: 92
Destroyed all images and cleared vector. New size = 0
Destroyed all images and cleared vector. New size = 0
Destroyed all images and cleared vector. New size = 0
Destroyed all images and cleared vector. New size = 0
Freeing image buffer at 0x7f2834000b80
free(): invalid pointer
```

**Can anyone explain if I am misunderstanding how vectors work, the `clear()` function specifically, or point me towards where I might be causing this issue?**

Editing to add output that shows even after clearing and having `size()` return 0, on the next `push_back()`s, the old values seem to reappear in the vector:

```
Vector size before 1st clear: 3
Freeing image buffer at 0x7f5e34fe6010
Freeing image buffer at 0x7f5e34b80010
Freeing image buffer at 0x7f5e3471a010
Vector size after 1st clear: 0
Vector size before 1st clear: 3
Freeing image buffer at 0x7f5e34db3010
Freeing image buffer at 0x7f5e3494d010
Freeing image buffer at 0x7f5e344e7010
Vector size after 1st clear: 0
c
Vector size before 2nd clear: 6
Freeing image buffer at 0x7f5e34fe6010
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Elephant in the room: Why not use another `vector` instead of the `calloc`s?

Comment: @user4581301 I did not write the apriltag library, and aside from that, it is a C library. Aside from both of those, I am trying to understand what is causing the vectors in this impl. to not work as expected more so than just fix the problem (if you see my edit, it shows that the vectors don't seem to be behaving as described when used in this way)

Comment: `uint8_t *buf = calloc(height*stride, sizeof(uint8_t));` -- If it is a `C` library, why isn't it checking for a NULL return here (and in other places)?

Comment: Right. I should have noticed the absence of the casts.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am not sure, as I did not write the apriltag library. I am basing that description off the .c file extension of all library files and the description of the library by the people who DID write it "AprilTag consists of a small C library with minimal dependencies."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
// This works fine
  for (auto vec : images){
    for (auto img : vec){
      image_u8_destroy(img);
    }
    vec.clear();
  }
```

LOOKS like it works fine but `auto vec`  in `for (auto vec : images)` is a value, not a reference. It makes a copy of the `vector` in `images`, and that means `vec.clear();` cleared a copy. The original in `images` still contains `image_u8` instances holding now-dangling pointers.

If I'd been paying attention to the

```
Vector size before 2nd clear: 6
```

diagnostic, I'd have figured this out an hour ago when the question was first asked. Good debugging. Asker was looking at the right stuff and just missed a detail that surprises a lot of people. In C++ unless you ask for a reference, or you're passing around arrays, you get a value.

Solution:

```cpp
// This REALLY works fine
  for (auto &vec : images){
    for (auto &img : vec){ // optional. You probably won't save much since `img` is 
                           // already a pointer
      image_u8_destroy(img);
    }
    vec.clear();
  }
```

Comment: Much appreciated. I don't use this style for loop often and wasn't thinking about that being the case, valuable lesson learned.

Comment: @DouglasB Sorry I wasn't paying enough attention to your debugging diagnostics earlier.